Showing PDF in in-app browser in Expo Go giving a blank page
I want to show a pdf based on what button a user clicks. This all works, but sometimes it open the webpage, but doesnt show the PDF, just a blank screen. When this happens, I need to manually refresh the page.
I use this code to open the webpage:
const pdfUrl = `url to pdf`;
const docsUrl = `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${pdfUrl}`;

await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(docsUrl);

I don't want to use the url to the pdf directly, because then it downloads the pdf.

Expected result:

Broken result:


have you tried to implement location.reload()?
